# can not get jquery to scroll to a position, no matter what I do

Tags: jquery, scroll

I just can't seem to get jquery to scroll to a position on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(400);
});
```

I tried replacing window, with about everything I could think of, what probably fundamental thing am i doing wrong.?

Thanks a lot for helping me out here

Edit: I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gameone/vj9v7x8r/2/) to examplify:

Sam

Comment: Try: `$('html, body').scrollTop(400);`. Most browsers use `html` (I believe) and then you add `body` for old IE (again, I believe). I haven't done this in a while but I remember there being a caveat to the selector. What browser are you seeing the problem with?

Comment: nope nothing, page stays on 0 on refresh

Comment: If you use the `ready` event like you are, it won't fire after the fact. If you use `$(function () { ... });` it will fire if bound after the `ready` event actually fires. I suggest you create a JSFiddle and isolate the code.

Comment: hi jasper, it's almost just this code, I'm testing.. could you please elaborate a bit on that syntax issue you pointed out above ? I think thats it

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() { $(window).scrollTop(400); });` is similar to `$(function () { $(window).scrollTop(400); });` but the latter will fire if bound both before or after the `document.ready` event fires. I brought that up because I think you have some issue not posted to this question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gameone/vj9v7x8r/2/

Comment: above you'll find a fiddle, which a non working example. A bit stupid I can't find the error in such a plain example. Anyway, Curious to hear what you say.. thx

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to include `jQuery`. Your `JSFiddle` does not contain `jQuery` Library.

Scroll thrugh `document` variable.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop(400);
});
```

Comment: Good one, was my first fiddle. It works now so thanks!
It's still not working in my main page though, have to figure out why that is.

Comment: in line with the comment of M1K1O you do not have opening bracket on 'html, body' reference. Also to run on jsfiddle select the jquery version from left-top menu under Frameworks & Extensions

Comment: Apparently, in my main document, if I change $(document).ready(function() {
to
$(document).click(function() {
it does work,

what could be wrong with the 'ready'?

Comment: @sam Post more of your code for more help. The code you posted in your question works on its own, so the issue is something else. It's likely there is a JS error in your browser's console that will help you debug.

Comment: @Jasper code in question was ubdated according to my answer for hidden reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
   window.onload = function() {
   $(document.body).scrollTop(100);
     };
```

This was the one that worked for me in FF. If anyone can explain on WHY, I'd be curious to hear...

Comment: Without you posing code that does not actually work, nobody can help you without taking stabs in the dark. The code you posted in your question works on its own, so the problem is elsewhere. Or maybe you need to be more specific with your issue, are there certain browsers that have issues and other that do not?